# How to get the binary values from map object (<map at 0x7f8adefd7c50>) in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this list of binary data:

```
 binary: 
[[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]]
```

I am trying to remove commas and space so that i will get 10 binary numbers,and need to convert to decimal.

```
decimal=0
numbers=[]
for i in range(0,len(binary)):
    numbers.append(map(float, str(binary[i]).split(',')))
    #print(list(numbers))
    decimal = decimal*2 + numbers[i]   ---->this line give error #TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'map'
```

Output of numbers is a map :

```
[<map at 0x7f8b62798080>,
 <map at 0x7f8b62798208>,
 <map at 0x7f8b627983c8>,
 <map at 0x7f8b62798588>,
 <map at 0x7f8b62798748>,..]
```

How to come out of this issue? Or is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easier (and therefore better) way is to use `int()` to perform the conversion of the binary string to an integer value:

```
>>> numbers = [int(''.join(str(bit) for bit in bits), 2) for bits in binary]
>>> numbers
[48, 16, 63, 16, 16, 16, 20, 20, 16, 20]
```

The second argument to `int()` specifies the base of the incoming data, base 2 being binary. The `''.join(str(bit) for bit in bits` converts the elements of each list item to strings which are then joined to create the bit string.